# python: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects when using multiprocessing.Queue()

Tags: python, python-3.x, load-testing, rate-limiting

I was doing load test, and want to send requests to server with a specific rate, so I use `RateLimiter` module to control request rate.

But it will raise error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

It seems to be because `Queue` object q was be used in `worker()` method:

```
q.put(pool.submit(predict, req))
```

How can I solve this problem?

my demo code:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, cpu_count
import time
from ratelimiter import RateLimiter      # pip install ratelimiter
from concurrent import futures

q = Queue()

def predict(req):
    # send a request and return the response
    # ...


def worker(q, req, process_id):
    pool = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 1000)
    rate_limiter = RateLimiter(max_calls=1000, period=1)
    while time.time() < time_end:
        with rate_limiter:
            q.put(pool.submit(predict, req))
            continue

processes = []
for i in range(num_processes):
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(q, req, i))    # req is a request object
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `_thread.RLock` object cannot be pickled. This is because it is a synchronization primitive that is used to protect access to shared resources in a multi-threaded environment.
Try to solve this issue by using a different synchronization primitive that can be pickled. Try using a `multiprocessing.Lock` object instead of an `_thread.RLock`.

Here is an example of how you can use `multiprocessing.Lock`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Lock

lock = Lock()

def worker(q):
    while True:
        req = q.get()
        if req is None:
            break
        with lock:
            result = predict(req)
        q.task_done()
        q.put(result)
```

My example does this:

1. Create a multiprocessing.Lock object.
2. Uses it to protect access to the shared resource (the predict function).
3. The with statement ensures that the lock is acquired before the code inside the block is executed and released when the block is exited.